# I am getting a SegFault error, but why?

Tags: c, linux

I am getting a Segmentation Fault error when I run the code, but other than that it compiles and runs. If you know why the error is occurring, I'd appreciate the help. Also please explain why it is occurring, as I'm curious.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    float att,def,hp,agi,stl,wis,ran,acc;
    char name[10],contents[100];
    int warrior,lvl=1,kills=0;

    printf("What is your name?\n");
    gets(name);

    printf("1: Ninja\n");
    printf("2: Knight\n");
    printf("3: Archer\n\n");
    printf("Pick a warrior.\n");
    scanf("%i",warrior);

    ...

    char attack[10],defense[10],health[10],agility[10],stealth[10],wisdom[10],range[10],accuracy[10],level[10],kill[10];
    snprintf(attack,10,"%f",att);
    snprintf(defense,10,"%f",def);
    snprintf(health,10,"%f",hp);
    snprintf(agility,10,"%f",agi);
    snprintf(stealth,10,"%f",stl);
    snprintf(wisdom,10,"%f",wis);
    snprintf(range,10,"%f",ran);
    snprintf(accuracy,10,"%f",acc);
    snprintf(level,10,"%f",lvl);
    snprintf(kill,10,"%f",kills);   

    char my_path[25];
    strcat(my_path,"Warriors/");
    strcat(my_path,name);
    strcat(my_path,".txt");


    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(my_path, "w+");

    fputs(attack, fp);
    fputs(" ", fp);
    fputs(defense, fp);
    fputs(" ", fp);
    fputs(health, fp);
    fputs(" ", fp);
    fputs(agility, fp);
    fputs(" ", fp);
    fputs(stealth, fp);
    fputs(" ", fp);
    fputs(wisdom, fp);
    fputs(" ", fp);
    fputs(range, fp);
    fputs(" ", fp);
    fputs(accuracy, fp);
    fputs(" ", fp);
    fputs(level, fp);
    fputs(" ", fp);
    fputs(kill, fp);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: But do use a debugger.

Comment: `scanf("%i",warrior);` --> `scanf("%i",&warrior);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What you've got is a trivial error (nonetheless common and with serious consequences).  One of the things you need to do is learn how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) — doing so would have given you a program of under 10 lines to show, and you might even have worked out what was wrong on your own.  Please note that [`gets()` is too dangerous to be used — ever](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/). And be cautious about mixing line inputs like `fgets()` with `scanf()` because [`scanf()` leaves the newline in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/)

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are following issues in the code.

1. Incorrect use of `scanf` while reading value for `warrior`.

   ```
   /* scanf("%i",warrior); */ // Put '&' before warrior
   scanf("%i",&warrior);
   ```
2. Incorrect format specifiers in `snprintf` while printing values of integers `lvl`, and `kills`.

   ```
   /* snprintf(level,10,"%f",lvl); */ // Change %f to %d
   snprintf(level,10,"%d",lvl);
   /* snprintf(kill,10,"%f",kills); */ // Change %f to %d
   snprintf(kill,10,"%d",kills);
   ```
3. Using `strcat` with `my_path` without initializing it.

   ```
   /* char my_path[25]; */ // Initialize as seen below 
   char my_path[25] = ""; 
   strcat(my_path,"Warriors_");
   strcat(my_path,name);
   strcat(my_path,".txt");
   ```
4. Finally, you are using `gets`, which should be avoided. You can change it to `fgets`.

---

Now coming to why your program is crashing.

First when you did `scanf("%i",warrior);`:  Instead of the address (i.e. `&warrior`) you gave the value of `warrior` variable. And since `warrior` was not initialized, it had an indeterminate value. Now `scanf` treated the value of `warrior` as an address and tried to write the value there. And, since the value of `warrior` was indeterminate, it invoked undefined behavior.

Second when you used `%f` instead of `%d` (mismatch of format specifier) in `snprintf`, the code again invoked undefined behavior.

Third, when you use `strcat` without initializing `my_path`, your array `my_path` will have indeterminate values. Now, `strcat` looks for value `0` starting from the address pointed by `my_path` and keeps on looking untill it finds a `0`. While doing this it may try to read value outside the array, again invoking undefined behavior.

When undefined behavior is invoked, anything can happen. In your case you got a segmentation fault.

---

**P.S.**: You should also check return value of `scanf` to check if it succeded or not.

**P.S.**: You should also check return value of `fopen` to check if it succeded or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%i",warrior);
```

`scanf` expects a pointer. http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf

Fix it to

```
scanf("%i", &warrior);
```

Comment: One more: `char my_path[25];` --> `char my_path[25] = "";`. Because OP uses `strcat` on that buffer.

Answer (score 0):

you'd better also add this kind of code to check if fopen is successful.

```
  if(fp==NULL)
  {   
      printf("can't open file:%s\n",my_path);
  }   
  else
  {
      ......
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

these two lines:

```
char my_path[25];
strcat(my_path,"Warriors/");
```

are incorrect because the `strcat()` function appends to the end of the current string (where it finds a NUL char '\0')

There is no telling where that NUL char will be found.

Suggest using:

```
char my_path[25];
strcpy(my_path,"Warriors/");
```